# How to tell if Angular 6 App is in production mode outside of Angular project

Tags: angular, google-analytics

I have some Google Analytics code that is outside of the Angular project. I only want to include it if the environment is production.

I know there is an environment variable *inside* the Angular project that you can reference like this inside typescript...

```
if (environment.production) {
  // do stuff
}
```

That doesn't help if there is some static code outside of Angular though. I tried putting the Google analytics code inside Angular, but that seems to have issues with the scope not being found and typescript didn't like it.

Right now the best solution I have is to manually check the hostname which probably isn't the best solution (this is in the index.html outside the angular app)...

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-00000000-0"></script>
<script>
        if(location.hostname === "productionurl.com") {
                // insert google analytics tracking code
                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}        
                gtag('js', new Date());        
                gtag('config', 'UA-000000000-0');
        }
</script>
```

I am used to using web.config files which would be simple, but this project uses an angular config instead to deal with environment variables.

Maybe there is a way to get the environment from something like "getAllAngularRootElements()" in vanilla javascript, but I haven't found a way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me the most clean solution at the moment is to use a second `index.html` file, for example `index.prod.html`, and make it replace the original one during the build process by using the `"fileReplacements"` property in the `"production"` env config inside `angular.json`.

Check here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments

**UDPATE for angular 8+**

While building, `"fileReplacements"` will not work for replacing the `index.html` - use `"index"` instead:

```
"index": {
  "input": "src/index.prod.html",
  "output": "index.html"
},
```

More info here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14599

Comment: This is a good solution. I have seen the file replace examples for other script files and such, but I didn't even think to swap out entire html files. Thanks for the easy and clean solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting up Google Analytics through Angulartics (https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics)? That should resolve your problem I think.

Comment: I am using Angulartics2 https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/tree/master/src/lib/providers/gtm

The instructions on that page say to put the normal angular setup code right after the body...which is outside the angular app.

When the page first loads it automatically registers a page hit. I can turn off the "startTracking" stuff later, but the original page enter still happens.

I guess it isn't that big of a deal, but it seemed like it would be neat if you could pull environment variables from the angular object since it is used to control the web project.

Comment: It actually says that you should put standard GTM code at the beginning of the `<body>`, and then to `import { Angulartics2GoogleTagManager } from 'angulartics2/gtm';`